# Почему после function expression надо ставить ; а после function declaration нет?

Tags: javascript

```
var f = function() {
};

function f() {
}
```

Comment: потому что `var f = function() {
};` по сути это переменная `f`, у которой в качестве значения функция...... а что мы делаем в конце объявления переменной? Ответ очевиден...... Например `var f = 666;` - точка с запятой. тут тоже самое

Comment: Потому что func. decl. это конструкция, а func. exp. - выражение.